# <img src="url" /> Где url - адрес скрипта. Допустимо ли?

Tags: html, html5, asp.net

Собственно хочу сделать так: `<img src="1.aspx" />`. Разумеется 1.aspx будет передавать не text/html, а скажем image/jpeg. 
 Например так:

```
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
response.WriteFile("1.jpg");
response.End();
```

Вопрос не только к ASP.NET разработчикам. Можно модифицировать так  `<img src="1.php" />`
Указанный выше код я проверял - все работает. Вопрос в другом: Законно ли это? Как на это смотрит w3c? Будет ли это работать во всех браузерах? или все таки url должен оканчиваться на .jpg (.gif)/(.png)... ?

Comment: Ну, как минимум, так делают, и довольно часто. Ещё в src можно всю картинку в виде base64 запищать, вообще без url. Тоже так делают... Так что, думаю, делайте смело. А по поводу w3c - проверьте страницу валидатором и узнаете :)

Comment: Изначально думал перехватывать запросы к captcha.jpg, добавив тэг в web.config. В общем-то получилось, но опасаюсь, что у преподавателя по другому сконфигурирован IIS или IIS Express, даже не знаю, как он там проверяет наши проекты, и в итоге перехват не сработает. Опасения появились, когда пример с перехватом, записанный нами в аудитории отказался работать дома , выдавая такое: `Обнаружены значения параметров ASP.NET, которые неприменимы в интегрированном режиме управляемого конвейера.`

Comment: думаю, можно смело использовать подход с скриптом в src. Чтобы проверить соответствие Вашей страницы стандартам консорциума, есть вот этот сервис: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: _"Будет ли это работать во всех браузерах"_ -- браузеры смотрят на HTTP-заголовки. чтобы вывести рисунок, браузеру не нужно даже имя файла. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим описание тэга [`img`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html) на *W3C*:

> src = non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces
>
> A URL referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image that is neither paged nor scripted.

Перевод:

> src = непустой URL, возможно, обрамлённый пробелами
>
> URL ссылается на неинтерактивную, возможно анимированную, картинку, которая не является страницей или скриптом.

Никаких ограничений на расширение файла в URL  нет. Более того, нет даже требования наличия *имени файла* в URL. Следовательно, можно любой валидный URL, который выдаст браузеру картинку.

Comment: Заголовок `Content-Type` только желательно при этом отправлять корректный. Далеко не все браузеры покажут картинку в `<img>`, если она пришла с типом `text/html`, например. А так - да, кроме `Content-Type`'а браузерам практически на всё наплевать.